# ¿Alguna una solución para este error generado con wordpress? No me permite ver la página ni el administrador

Tags: wordpress

```
Fatal error: Cannot use WPaaS\Plugin as Plugin because the name is already in use in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data03/26/3062226/html/wp-content/mu-plugins/gd-system-plugin/includes/log/components/trait-plugin-helpers.php on line 5
```

Este error aparece al abrir el contenido del sitio y al intentar ingresar al administrador de wordpress, también. 
Parece ser que es un error que esta ocurriendo en varias páginas. A la vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: 
Ese error ha aparecido alguna vez en sitios webs alojados por Go-Daddy.

Un usuario de Go-Daddy ha posteado una posible solución en stackoverflow en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42256380/5587982

Según él, es necesario renombrar la carpeta mu-plugins, accediendo a tu cuenta de hosting vía ftp a la carpeta: /home/content/p3pnexwpnas14_data03/26/3062226/html/

Si esto no funciona, dejo aquí debajo otras posibilidades:

De acuerdo al mensaje de error, hay un problema con un plugin almacenado en la carpeta mu-plugins. Se trata de un tipo especial de plugins que se ejecutan antes que el resto de los demás y sirven para varias cosas, entre ellas para usar varios plugins en instalaciones Wordpress con dominios múltiples [aquí](https://neliosoftware.com/es/blog/conoces-los-plugins-must-use-mu-plugin-de-wordpress/) tienes más info sobre esto.

Esto puede ser causado por algún plugin reciente que hayas instalado y que esté dando conflicto, o por algún plugin instalado a través de un script de tu compañía de hosting.

Si es así, 1º procedería a desactivar ese o esos últimos plugins instalados para comprobar si el error viene de ahí.

En caso contrario:

Si tienes acceso ftp a tu cuenta de hosting el problema se debería resolver accediendo vía ftp y borrando la carpeta gd-system-plugin situada en la ruta html/wp-content/mu-plugins/ , **eso sí, antes de borrar, haz una copia en local de dicha carpeta, de forma que la puedas restablecer si hay algún problema, subiendo de nuevo la copia que habrás hecho en tu equipo**

Antes de borrar, miraría lo que hay en la línea 5 del archivo trait-plugin-helpers.php tratando de encontrar una posible pista.

Saludos.

Comment: No me deja entrar ni al administrador de wp. Contacte al proveedor y según me dicen sería un problema con el update de la versión de los wordpress instalados en los sitios, y que wordpress esta trabajando en ello, por eso el origen de este error. Me dicen que habría que esperar, que han renombrado el folder de plugins de manera temporal.
De hecho hicieron lo mismo que la respuesta posteada en inglés, cambiar el nombre, me acabo de fijar.

Y yo accesando al archivo que marca el error, esta ubicado al principio del archivo y es: use WPaaS\Plugin;
Saludos

Comment: Me refiero a entrar en tu cuenta de hosting vía ftp, no vía el administrador de Wordpress. De este modo podrás ver si efectivamente la carpeta mu-plugins ha sido renombrada, y si no podrás renombrarla e incluso borrarla, haciendo previamente una copia de seguridad de la misma en tu disco local o en otra carpeta fuera de la carpeta plugins. Allí podrás revisar también la línea de error indicada en el archivo trait-plugin-helpers.php  que podría ayudar a determinar de dónde viene el error.

Comment: Si, ingrese vía ftp y vi que ya esta renombrada justo con el nombre de la respuesta en inglés.
Y el error en la linea es al principio del código con el use: 
use WPaaS\Plugin;
En goDaddy varios usuarios en inglés postearón este mismo error, originado, pienso que es por lo que me dijerón del update de wordpress. ¿Cree que sea por eso msimo?

Comment: Es posible que sea un error de Go-Daddy entonces y si están sobre ello lo solucionarán pronto.

Comment: Al contrario, me dijerón que es wordpress el problema con el update de versiones, y me dijerón que es todo lo que pueden hacer por ahora, que habría que esperar a que wordpress termine de estabilizarlo.

Comment: No creo. De ser así, todos los sitios con Wordpress estarían dando el mismo problema. Yo tengo un sitio con Wordpress, en un hosting diferente y puedo acceder a mi área de administración :)

Comment: Ya veo, Pues solamente que sea problema del hosting entonces, y lo esten reparando. por que más usuarios colocarón el mismo problema en su foro, pero ahorita ya no se encuentran esas publicaciones. Pareciera que las quitarón en godaddy

Comment: Sigue el mismo problema en, me preocupa. ¿que podrá yo hacer?